# X-Cart payment problem - vague error message

Tags: php, ssl, payment, x-cart

First of all, I'm not entirely sure stackoverflow is the place for this question, but registration on the x-cart forums is broken (you can sign up, but don't have permission to see anything,) google wasn't helpful and I've nowhere else to turn!

Anyway, I'm trying to use the directone payment method with x-cart, and it returns this error after checkout:

```
Order processing error
Order declined.
Review your data or contact the store administrator.

Reason: Response: System Error
Go Back
```

Not very helpful. Just wondered if anyone could at least point me in the right direction? Is there a more detailed log kept somewhere? Is there a great font of knowledge I should know about for things like this??

Thanks in advance,
John.

Comment: Not a programming question, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was fairly simple - for x-cart to integrate with directone, I needed to setup a password and IP for x-cart to access the directone API. All working now.